# SAS: Putting observations in bin and keep the ones closest to it

Tags: sas, data-manipulation, bin

I have a list of observations with a few variables. I need to put them in a bin (below) and only keep one observation in each bin which is closest to the bin's number:

- Bins
- 0.94
- 0.96
- 0.98
- 1.00
- 1.02
- 1.04
- 1.06

Data

```
Variable    Price   Value_to_bin    Closest bin
a   0.630527682     0.935                0.94
b   0.441296291     0.979                0.98
c   0.350173415     0.969   
d   0.920932417     0.993   
e   0.361863025     0.959                0.96
f   0.027205755     1.003                1
g   0.878286791     1.045   
h   0.206434946     0.971   
i   0.259272294     1.021                1.02
j   0.081774863     0.982   
k   0.01146324      0.992   
l   0.283027273     1.037                1.04
m   0.188747537     0.993   
n   0.554786        1.064                1.06
o   0.784774        1.065
```

And then just keep the ones that are closest to the bin value (i.e. delete the ones that have blanks in the 'closest_bin' variable.

I tried to use proc rank but I can't get rid of the rest or match with the bin (something like 'closest' doesn't exist as far as I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS SQL with automatic remerging can perform the query quite succinctly.  The consistent binning to a 0.02 level allows the `ROUND` function to compute the bin values to the nearest 0.02 unit.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    var,
    price,
    value,
    round(value,0.02) as valbin_02
  from have
  group by valbin_02
  having abs(valbin_02-value) = min(abs(valbin_02-value))
  ;
```